# Rig wont parent w model

Tags: animation, rigging

[image][image]So I made a custom rig for a model I downloaded. I made sure everything was in order and went to parent w automatic weights but it didn't work. none of the armatures parented w the rig. and I mean none. I can control the rig but it doesn't move the model. im pretty new and this is my first rig.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r35PWAvEdGyYXS49h2s9KbPv4GIk5a7U/view?usp=sharing) @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

First apply the scale of the armature. The problem is that the mesh is both dense (which is not very good for animation by the way, maybe you should unsubdivide) and small, which makes the calculation hard, you need to scale up both the object and armature, parent, then scale down to the original size.

Comment: when i do this it scales down the model once parented but keeps the armatures the same size

Comment: apply the scale of the armature (Ctrl A), select both the body and armature, scale up 4 times (S+4), parent, scale down 0.25 (S+0.25), it should work

Comment: i added a sc in the original question of what happens when the steps you provided are applied

Comment: you need to scale in Object mode, not Pose mode